# Regarding ORA 21000

Tags: database, oracle10g

I am struggling with an ORA 21000 which says **ORA-21000: error number argument to raise_application_error of 3739 is out of range**.

This error is coming intermittently.  I am not sure why this is occurring.  This worked absolutely fine earlier, but after migrating to Linux from Solaris, this error has suddenly come up.  Googling it didn't help.  Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` is a method by which an application can raise a custom error in Oracle, which is why there will be no documentation about your error message.

This procedure accepts an error number argument, which must be in the range -20000 to -20999. Looks like your application is trying to raise 3739 which is not allowed.

This is a defect in your application.

Comment: Yes, but I have searched everywhere in my application and this error code 3739 is nowhere to be found.  Any reason why it has started to show up suddenly?  And I did not find anything related to ORA 3739...

Comment: You will have to trace it back to its source somehow. Examine all calls to `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` in your code, perhaps the error code is being passed via a variable (although, hopefully, it is encoded in a constant somewhere).