# which Raise application error number should be used

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-trigger

I am creating a trigger for my database. In my trigger code which number argument should I use :

```
set serveroutput on

create or replace trigger iss_bk 
  after insert on Issue 
  for each row
declare
  p integer;
  q integer;
begin
  select Available_copy 
    into p 
    from book 
    where Book.ISBN = :NEW.book_id;

  q := p - :NEW.quantity;

  if q < 0 then
     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-1722,' Exceeded available quantity of book .');
  else
     update Book set 
       Available_copy = q 
       where Book.ISBN = :NEW.book_id;
  end if;    
end;
/
```

While q < 0 input is given, the error is :

```
ORA-21000: error number argument to raise_application_error of -1722 is out of range
ORA-06512: at "R1507090.ISS_BK", line 9
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regarding ORA 21000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918692/regarding-ora-21000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/errors.htm) (pick another version, if needed, but I don't think that much has chanaged). the "Handling PL/SQL Errors" says:

> ```
> raise_application_error(error_number, message[, {TRUE | FALSE}]);
> ```
>
> where
>
> - error_number is a negative integer in the range -20000 .. -20999
> - message is a character string up to 2048 bytes long.
> - If the optional third parameter is TRUE, the error is placed on the stack of
>     previous errors. If the parameter is FALSE (the default), the error
>     replaces all previous errors.

It means that you should use, for example,

```
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Exceeded available quantity of book.');
```

The same `ERROR_NUMBER` value can be reused, i.e. *all* your own error messages can share the same "-20001" code, if you want.